# Too many spam comments

Tags: websites

My website is receiving too many spam comments, what I do?
I have installed a plugin but I'm not satisfied with it.
How to block spam comments and spam users etc.

Comment: Interesting that a question about spam includes a link to your website... This is not a security question. Try asking (without your site link) over at [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). But be sure to include exactly what you've done and why it isn't working for you.

Comment: An solution when you have bots that are spamming you: What you can do is to place an hidden input field that you send along with your form. The hidden input is empty when a "normal" user sends the comment because they are not filling an hidden input field. But bots are filling in each input field. When the field is filled in you can ignore it in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the spam comments are to blog posts or similar...configure a CAPTCHA so that a successful response to the challenge is required prior to a comment being posted or a contact form being submitted. It should reduce the number of automated responses.

CAPTCHA modules are available for most web software packages.

More about CAPTCHAs [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA).

Answer (score 0):

Using `CAPTCHA` alone you cannot deal with SPAM comments as most of them are done manually.

- Using CAPTCHA : You can filter auto automated / bot comments.
- Manual Comments : Most of the SPAM comments are done to create back-links to their blogs. So, first of all just remove functionality of link to commenter's website from your website. So, just didn't ask for user's website and don't provide link back to user's website.
- Disallow HTML comments : So, now just make rendering of comments as text instead of HTMl so, that user can't post links in comments pannel.

So, now as you are no longer useful for them .. You can see considerable amount of reduce in SPAM comments.

Comment: I'v never heard that spam comments are mostly manual. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @schroeder well i have a team which do the same for entire day to make backlinks.. SPAM here i'm referring to comments not related to content on the page/article.

Comment: Maybe you need to automate that process? Also, the question here is about spam comments, and I'm not sure that given the scale of the problem that 'most' of it is manual.

Comment: Actually most of sites uses some sort of SPAM prevention mechanism like CAPTCHA already .. so making manual comments is the easiest way around.

Comment: There are lots of libraries that can bypass CAPTCHA. So, you don't have a source for your first statement? You are only extrapolating from your own procedures?